# Kickstart netinstall ignores kickstart file hosted in LAN and proceeds with manual installation

Tags: centos, system-installation, kickstart

Virtual machines are hypervised by vmware workstation.

I start my web server on vm1 - `192.168.0.31` running centos 7. I create and upload the kickstart file `ks.cfg` to `192.168.0.31/ks.cfg`. You can look at the file below.

Every vm in my LAN can access the `ks.cfg` and read its content by going to `192.168.0.31/ks.cfg`. I boot vm2 with netinstall iso of centos 7 and add `ks=http://192.168.0.31/ks.cf` to boot options and press enter. The only thing that comes to my mind is that somehow the mirror address in `ks.cfg` is not valid but i copied it from official centos site and tried multiple ones. I also tried mirrors found on the net, none of them solved the issue.

### ks.cfg

```
#platform=x86, AMD64, or Intel EM64T
#version=DEVEL
# Install OS instead of upgrade
install
# Keyboard layouts
keyboard 'us'
# Use network installation
url --url="http://mirrors.mit.edu/centos/7/os/x86_64/"
# System language
lang en_US
# System authorization information
auth  --useshadow  --passalgo=sha512
# Use graphical install
graphical
# SELinux configuration
selinux --enforcing
# Do not configure the X Window System
skipx

# Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled
# Network information
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0
# Halt after installation
halt
# System timezone
timezone Africa/Abidjan
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr
# Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fault was kickstart file not including all necessary information for the automated installation to take place. The network is working fine. If the `ks.cfg` fails to get fetched the following message would appear:[image]
If the `ks.cfg` gets fetched successfully but the contents are insufficient the following could greet us: [image]

To fix `No disks selected` define partitioning manually in GUI. Or use automatic partitioning (impossible in GUI, leaving everything blank won't result in automatic partitioning) - `ks.cfg` needs to be edited, just add `autopart --type=lvm` to the `# System bootloader configuration` section of the file. To fix `Nothing selected` in `SOFTWARE SELECTION` I just added the following:

```
%packages
%end
```

at the end of the file.

**TL;DR:**

After creating kickcstart file in GUI there will be need to supplement it with:

```
%packages
%end
```

If auto partitioning is wanted it can be done by supplementing the file with: `autopart --type=lvm` in `# System bootloader configuration` section.
My mistake in that particular situation was leaving all partitioning options blank in GUI thinking it will result in automatic partitioning.